# WHERE _Table_Suffix BETWEEN CAST(format_date('%Y%m%d',current_date() - 13) AS STRING) AND CAST(format_date('%Y%m%d',current_date()) AS STRING)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In query how shud we change the -13 days value to start date from 01-01-2022 in sql ?

WHERE _Table_Suffix BETWEEN CAST(format_date('%Y%m%d',current_date() - 13) AS STRING)
AND CAST(format_date('%Y%m%d',current_date()) AS STRING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try try replacing `current_date() - 13` with `DATE '2022-01-01'`. This will read as `from 1-jan-2022 to current date`; is this what you want?